# Disable urlbar filter - Firefox 28

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, browser, xss

I want to demonstrate DOM "Local" Based Cross Site Scripting on Firefox ver. 28.

I have this script on index.php

`<SCRIPT>
var pos=document.URL.indexOf("jmeno=")+6;
document.write(document.URL.substring(pos,document.URL.length));
</SCRIPT>`

And i want to run XSS by opening URL

`www.mydomain.com/index.php?jmeno=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>`

In IE11 I simply disable XSS Filter in Security setings and script works.

Altrought in Firefox there is solution by **disabling** this filter: `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` in `about:config`. This solution have no effect. Script is always escaped.

Is there any solution how to get work this script in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` does not attempt to filter data from entered URLs, it's not an analogue of IE's misguided anti-XSS filter. It's only about showing `javascript:` URLs in history lookup and it's irrelevant here.

Your example URL doesn't work for me in any browser, because the characters `<` and `>` are invalid to include in URLs at all. Browsers correct them to the URL-encoded versions `%3C` and `%3E`automatically when you enter them. So when you access `location.href` you get a URL with %-encoded angle brackets. Processing it with naïve string slicing leaves the encoded versions there so the tag doesn't parse.

Calling `decodeURIComponent()` over the extracted substring makes the example correctly vulnerable(!). (Though extracting a query parameter reliably in general is a bit more complicated.)

Comment: I tried to add `decodeURIComponent()` in script: 
`<SCRIPT>
var pos=document.URL.indexOf("jmeno=")+6;
pos = pos.decodeURIComponent(pos);
document.write(document.URL.substring(pos,document.URL.length));
</SCRIPT>`

but now i get error "pos.decodeURIComponent is not function"

Comment: `pos` is a number, the index in the string. You would decode the extracted substring.